# выбор параграфов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужен "регексп" для выборки многострочной порции текста между нумерацией параграфов. У меня получилось взять только первую строку.

Текст:

```
> лалала - текст-шапка ненужный 
> 
> 1. 
>    текст текст
>    текст текст
> 
> 2.
>    #$!...разные символы
> 
> 3. bla1 bla1 bla1 
>    бла1 бла1 бла1
> 
> 4. bla2 bla2 bla2 
>   bla2 bla2 bla2 
> 
> лалалала - текст-хвост, можно оставить болтаться с пунктом №4
```

Регексп (берет только первую строку):

```
preg_match_all("**/\d\.\n(.*?)$/um**", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Результат данного регекспа:

> array(    ...     1   =>  array(4         0   =>  aaaaaaaaa       1   =>  #$!...разные символы
>         2   =>  bla1 bla1 bla1          3   =>  bla2 bla2 bla2      ) )

[ссылка на example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gTz)(переключитесь на preg_match_all).

Вопрос: как сделать выборку всех строк между номерами параграфов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
/^\d+\.\n(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)$/um
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/aR9tK1/1)

*Подробности*:

- `^` - начало строки (линии)
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `\.\n` - точка + символ перевода строки
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)` - Подмаска №1:

  - `.*` - 0+ символов, отличных от символа перевода строки
  - `\n(?!\n)` - символ перевода строки, после которого нет другого такого же символа
  - `.*` - 0+ символов, отличных от символа перевода строки
- `$`

[PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/5vtcek):

```
$re = '~^\d+\.\n(.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)$~um'; 
$input_lines = "лалала - текст ненужный \n\n1.\naaaaaaaaa\n\n2.\n#\$!...разные символы\n\n3.\nbla bla bla\nбла бла бла\n\n4.\nbla bla bla\nлалалала\n\nлалалала - текст-хвост, можно оставить болтаться с пунктом №4\n"; 
preg_match_all($re, $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array[1]);
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо!